# batch script to copy all usr files from sub folders to separate folders

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script which will copy all usr files from the sub folders inside a directory into 2 separate folders and then delete the files from their original places. 
So far I have done:

```
for /R S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI %%f in (*.usr) do copy T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest

for /R S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI %%f in (*.usr) do copy T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup
```

This however is not copying the files and nothing is happening, where have I gone wrong here? And what would I need to add to delete the files from their original folders as well?

Edit:

From how I was reading the answers I thought it should become:

```
for /R "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI" %%f in (*.usr) do copy %%F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest"

for /R "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI" %%f in (*.usr) do copy %%F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup"
```

but this still is not working. I'm guessing I just haven't understood properly what was being said

Edit 2:

I added the PAUSE command at the end of the script to see what was happening when it was run and this is what comes up :

```
S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>for /R "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI" %f in (*.usr) do copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest"

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>for /R "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI" %f in (*.usr) do copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup"

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy %F "T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Hopefully the last edit.

Now I've got

```
for /R "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI" %%G in (*.usr) do copy %%G "T:\edidata\NetEDI\Outboxtest"

for /R "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI" %%G in (*.usr) do copy %%G "T:\edidata\NetEdi\Outbox backup"

PAUSE
```

but it's still not working right, the output given is:

```
S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>for /R "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI" %G in (*.usr) do copy %G "T:\edidata\NetEDI\Outboxtest"

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\gentest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEDI\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Asda\asdatest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEDI\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Costcutter\CCINV24052020.usr "T:\edidata\NetEDI\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Costcutter\cctest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEDI\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\McColls Local Account\mccollstest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEDI\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Scotmid\scotmidtest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEDI\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Tesco\tescotest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEDI\Outboxtest"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>for /R "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI" %G in (*.usr) do copy %G "T:\edidata\NetEdi\Outbox backup"

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\gentest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEdi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Asda\asdatest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEdi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Costcutter\CCINV24052020.usr "T:\edidata\NetEdi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Costcutter\cctest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEdi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\McColls Local Account\mccollstest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEdi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Scotmid\scotmidtest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEdi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.

S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI>copy S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\Tesco\tescotest.usr "T:\edidata\NetEdi\Outbox backup"
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So what I'm gathering is that it is now getting the files but, it can't find the folders to copy them to? The file destination is correct for them both, I've double-checked so not sure what else could be wrong.

Comment: The hardest problems are when they're staring you in the face...perhaps changing `%%F` to `%%f` or vice versa will help you out. And the problem with your latest version using `%%G` , as well as in the previous one, is that they need to be doublequoted, because they have a space character in their names `"%%G"`, `"%%F"`, and/or `"%%f"`.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the double quotes sorted that and it is now copying the files. Don't suppose you know for deleting the files form their original folders, would it be the same structure but instead of do copy would it be do delete?

Comment: Give it a try on a test directory tree, and see what happens! Please make sure it is a test directory tree though, because there's a very strong possibility that it will work!

Comment: @lross12 Yes, it should work. If not, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of extending this one which has become pretty complex already.

Comment: I wouldn't have said it was complex @Melebius, the issue only became so, when answers were posted which missed the **glaringly obvious syntax issues**!

Comment: I'm guessing I'm doing something obviously wrong again for deleting but I tried for /R "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI\test" %%G in (*.usr) do del which gives a syntax incorrect error and if I do do delete then I get a not recognised as an internal or external command error

Comment: realised what it was, forgot to add "%%G" after do del, thanks everyone for their help!

Comment: Replace `copy %%F "…"` by `copy "%%F" "…"` or even `copy "%%~F" "…"`…

Comment: To debug a batch file it is best to open a Command Prompt window and run it from there by typing in its path/name and pressing *Enter* rather than double-clicking its icon…

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three problems in your commands.

1. You are providing just one argument to the `copy` command. It needs *source* **and** *destination*. You probably forgot to use the `%%F` argument provided by `for`.

   ```
   for /R <path> %%f in (*.usr) do copy %%F T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest
   ```
2. Another problem is that your path contains spaces and you are not escaping them. You should surround your path by double quotes:

   ```
   "S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI"
   ```

   The same problem most likely applies to `T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup`. The current command

   ```
   for /R S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI %%f in (*.usr) do copy T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup
   ```

   would copy from `T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox` to `.\backup`.

   You must use quotes for your parameter, too, as it expands to a path containing spaces in your case!

   ```
   ... do copy "%%f" T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest
   ```

   It’s generally better to use underscores (`_`) or hyphens (`-`) instead of spaces in paths, then you don’t need to escape the spaces in each command.
3. The `%%f` [argument is case-sensitive](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), it cannot be referenced as `%%F`.

Comment: so instead of do copy it should be copy %%F ?

Comment: @lross12 Keep the `do`, it’s a part of the [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) syntax.

Comment: would you be able to look at my edit? Because I still don't think I'm understanding properly how it should be done

Comment: so with your edit, does that mean that the folder name should be changed to something like Outbox-backup or would it be fine as it is?

Comment: @lross12 It should work with spaces, too, but if you did not use them, you’d save some work. Also see my update reflecting your updated question.

Comment: So I added the pause command so I could see what was happening and it is saying it cannot find the file specified. I'm not sure if it is meaning the files I want to copy or the folders I want them copied to? I've updated my question to show what happens

Comment: @lross12 OK, checked it myself and found the problem. Some letters, like `f`, are reserved.

Comment: sorry hopefully this is the last time. I've updated the question because after doing what you suggested it seems to be getting the files but not able to find the folders where I want them copied? The file destination is correct, I've double checked so not sure what else is could be? Also do you know what I would need to add in order to delete the files from their original folders as well after they have been copied?

Comment: @lross12 Well, well, the destination might be correct but the source is not as it contains spaces, again… See my updated answer (the end of part 2).

Comment: Concerning 3.: I don't know what exactly you mean by *»pathname format letters«*, but I fuess you are talking about the `~`-modifiers; if so, I can tell you there is no collision, you can use either `%%F` or `%%G`, there is no difference; but in the `copy` command line there must be quotes too: `copy "%%~F" "…"`…

Comment: Yes, because `for` meta-variables are case-sensitive; the OP specifies `%%f` for the loop but uses `%%F` in the body then…

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks, this seems to be the correct explanation. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should do:

```
... copy %%f T:\edidata\netedi\Outboxtest\ (or ...Outbox\test\)
```

... and what's the story of T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox backup? Shouldn't that be:

```
... copy %%f T:\edidata\netedi\Outbox\backup\
```

Comment: ah okay thanks, I'll give that a go.he Outbox backup is the name of the folder

Comment: Does that name contain a space? In that case, it might be better to use double quotes for the name: T:\edidata\...\"Outbox backup".

Comment: The filename was clearly shown in the original code @Dominique, `S:\Customer Services\EDI\NET EDI`, was the root for the recursion, therefore every single result passed to `Do` must have had at least those two spaces in their names!